# Saving previous page parameters js, jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm currently working on one project which uses jsp, javascript, spring among others. I have a search page implemented where user can search by different criteria. (e.g. http://localhost:8080/service/timesheet/view?status=A&size=100&sort=startDate,asc&page=0&f_startDate_gte=2016-02-01&f_endDate_lte=2016-02-29)
When I click on some entry in this page I am redictered to the new page where a single item is shown. Now I want in this page to have a button which will bring me back to the search page but with the previous configured criterias. But the thing is that I can acces to those single item pages also from other points in application. What would be the best way to do this? Does it need to be done with passing parameters from jacaScript and checking out what was the previous visited page? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

put it in user session object with a key that uniquely identify it. then you can make the decision based on that key/object pair.

Comment: but if I access an item page from some other page other then the search page, then it would redirected me to previous search with customized criteria which I don't want. Should I then reset these values every time a page is accessed from a page other then the search page?

Comment: exactly. thats the correct way to go if you are staying with old school jsp